# datagrid has no property datasource

Tags: datagrid, datasource

I couldnt use dataSource property of dataGrid ?

my usings are

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Windows;

using System.Windows.Controls;

using System.Windows.Data;

using System.Windows.Documents;

using System.Windows.Input;

using System.Windows.Media;

using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

using System.Windows.Navigation;

using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;

using System.Data;

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 3;
                dataGrid2.DataSource///////////////does not come up :S

                ExcelData exceldata = new ExcelData();
                this.dataGrid2.DataContext = exceldata;


            }
```

what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

it's `DataSource` not `Datasource`

Comment: It was only to show u it didnt appeared when I wrote dataGrid2.Data.... ?? understand me It was onlt DataContext came up

Comment: is DataSource the only thing that don't appear or everything don't appear?

Comment: Only thing other dataContext and dataContextChanged are appear.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Take a look at [DataGrid Datasource property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.datasource.aspx)

also windows Datagrid does not have any Datacontext property

Take a look at [Windows Datagrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.aspx)

Comment: I looked but nothing man . It is not about using criteria then about what?